# How to find which table that contain specific data

Tags: sqlite

Lets say i have Database with to tables (division_1,division_2)
each table have the same columns ( id, name , salary)
and Jone is person in one of these tables
is there a query in SQL that return in which division Jone is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `union` to select from both tables and see which contains the record

```
select 'division1' as div from division_1 where name = 'Jone'
union
select 'division2' as div from division_2 where name = 'Jone'
```

BTW if you have the possibility to change the DB design, then do it. There should only be one division table with a column that indicates which one it is.

Comment: that was really helpful, i'm changing my DB design , thanks for the help